# Combination of Boost ICL and Boost Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to use the Boost Serialization library to archive Boost ICL interval sets (because I couldn't find any other more or less standard ways to serialize them). I want to split the `serialize` function into two functions `save` and `load`. Sorry to say, I'm stuck in the `load` function for now - I can't save even the size of the interval set.
My testing program is below. The compiler complains about the line `A << IS.iterative_size()`, which is strange cause the return type of the `iterative_size()` function is the `size_t`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

#include <boost/icl/discrete_interval.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>

const std::string Filename = "tmp.archive";

typedef boost::icl::discrete_interval<int> Interval;
typedef boost::icl::interval_set<int> IntervalSet;

namespace boost
{
  namespace serialization
  {

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive& A, const IntervalSet& IS, const unsigned int)
    {
      A << IS.iterative_size();
      // ...
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive& A, IntervalSet& IS, const unsigned int)
    {
      // ...
    }

    template<class Archive>
    inline void serialize(Archive& A, IntervalSet& IS, const unsigned int V)
    {
      split_free(A, IS, V); 
    }

  }
}

int main()
{
  std::ofstream f(Filename);
  if (f.good())
  {
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(f);
    IntervalSet s;
    s += Interval::closed(100, 200); 
    oa << s;
    f.close();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

(Compiler - GCC 4.8.1, Boost - 1.55.0, OS - Xubuntu 3.11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iterative_size()` doesn't return a `lvalue`, which is required. You can't usefully deserialize derived properties anyways (in much the same way as a vector doesn't (de)serialize the `size()` member result. Instead, it serializes all data, and the `size()` happens to end up being the same in the end.

Also look at

> If there is no such default constructor, the function templates `load_construct_data` and perhaps `save_construct_data` will have to be overridden. Here is a simple example

From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html)

which can probably be used beneficially in cases where object instances get initialized from (non-default) constructor parameters only.

**Update** Here's a demo implementation: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5ec73faafcab9f)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>

#include <boost/icl/discrete_interval.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace serialization {

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void save(Archive& ar, boost::icl::discrete_interval<V> const& di, unsigned) {
            auto const& bb = di.bounds().bits();
            auto const& l  = di.lower();
            auto const& u  = di.upper();

            ar << bb << l << u;
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void load(Archive& ar, boost::icl::discrete_interval<V>& di, unsigned) {
            auto bb = di.bounds().bits();
            V    l, u;

            ar >> bb >> l >> u;

            di = boost::icl::discrete_interval<V>(l, u, boost::icl::interval_bounds(bb));
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::icl::discrete_interval<V>& di, unsigned v) {
            split_free(ar, di, v);
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void save(Archive& ar, boost::icl::interval_set<V> const& is, unsigned) {
            auto sz = is.iterative_size();

            ar & sz;
            for (auto& di : is) ar & di;
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void load(Archive& ar, boost::icl::interval_set<V>& is, unsigned) {
            is.clear();

            size_t sz;
            ar & sz;

            size_t counter = sz;

            while (counter--) {
                typename boost::icl::interval_set<V>::value_type di;
                ar & di;
                is.insert(is.end(), di);
            }

            assert(is.iterative_size() == sz);
        }

    template <typename Archive, typename V>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, boost::icl::interval_set<V>& is, unsigned v)
        {
            split_free(ar, is, v);
        }
} }

const std::string Filename = "tmp.archive";

typedef boost::icl::discrete_interval<int> Interval;
typedef boost::icl::interval_set<int> IntervalSet;

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream f(Filename);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(f);
        IntervalSet s;
        s += Interval::closed(100, 200); 
        s += Interval::left_open(30,45);
        s += Interval::right_open(77, 78);

        oa << s;
    }
    {
        std::ifstream f(Filename);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(f);

        IntervalSet s;
        ia >> s;

        std::cout << "Deserialized: ";
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Interval>(std::cout, " "));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Deserialized: (30,45] [77,78) [100,200]
```

Comment: why does the `<<` operator need the `lvalue`? I thought that the splitting the `serialize` into the `save/load` pair would be enough to get rid of the automatic substitution `&` by `<<` and `>>`

Comment: @HEKTO Don't ask me. If you're gonna ask me, I'll guess it is for symmetry with `serialize(Archive&ar, T& v, unsigned)` which is required to support both the loading and saving.

Comment: Well, I was able to implement `save/load` functions using intermediate `std::vector` - it's not very interesting, but works. Anyway, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @HEKTO FWIW here's my take on it - no need for temporary vectors **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb5ec73faafcab9f)**